# How can I run a specific script without running these commands every time I want to activate my virtual environment on Windows?

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

I have a virtual python environment where I work with python projects, but every time I want to start this environment I have to run PowerShell window as administrator, go to the folder where ***env*** is and run the following commands:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

I know this could be fixed by changing the execution policies to allow running unsigned local scripts, but I don't want that, I just want that ***activate*** script to run my virtual environment.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand ... you know you can specify the execution policy when starting a PowerShell console, don't you? Run `PowerShell /?` to read more about.